# How to run jar files sequentially from a shell script

Tags: java, linux, docker, sh

I am trying to run two java application one after other in my docker container.
In my dockerfile i have specified invoker.sh as the entry point.

`ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "/opt/invoker.sh"]`

Then i use this script to run two jar files.

```
#!/bin/sh
java -jar loader.jar
java -jar service.jar
```

but this does not work. It gives

> *Error: Unable to access jarfile javaimpl-loader.jar*

and only the service.jar is executed. When i tried `echo $(ls)` it shows that both the jar files are there.

but if i change the script to

```
#!/bin/sh
echo $(java -jar loader.jar)
java -jar service.jar
```

then both the jars work. Why cant i use the 1st script. any help regarding this highly apreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the first example is being treated as a single line, you could work with that. Also, I would prefer `bash` to `/bin/sh`. Like,

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
java -jar loader.jar && java -jar service.jar
```

Comment: thank you for the reply. it actually worked. But I have a follow up question.
will this ensure that the jar files will run one after the other?

Comment: @KosalaLakshitha As long as the first process exits with `0` (which is usually "SUCCESS").